# Elementor CSS load in footer after using get_builder_content_for_display($id)

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

My goal is to build Elementor Header builder, i have created a custom post type and design some block using elementor and then with help of this following code display anywhere.

`echo \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->frontend->get_builder_content_for_display($template_id);`

but the issue is when i use it as a header in few page [Like: blog, archive, 404] CSS loads in footer that's why some issue create because of CSS priority. but if i edit some page with elementor and see the footer and css it load properly in header.